# Did James Monroe and James Madison ever disagree?

Tags: united-states, president

I can't seem to find anything that they did butt heads about.

Did they ever have any public disagreements that were recorded by history?

Answer (score 5):

In 1806 James Monroe, at the time serving as the US minister to Britain, [tried to renew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe%E2%80%93Pinkney_Treaty) the [Jay Treaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay_Treaty) of 1795. However, both Thomas Jefferson and James Madison (then Secretary of State) rejected the treaty. Monroe's and Madison's differing opinions about foreign affairs came up again in 1808, when Monroe was considered by parts of the Democratic-Republican Party as a presidential candidate, instead of Madison.

However, the two men's relations were amicable, to the point where Madison named Monroe his Secretary of State in 1811, and then Secretary of War in 1814.

Comment: To be fair, James Monroe's job at the time was to create that treaty. If he'd been in any other position, he may well have had the same opinion on it as the rest of his party. The [party divide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Republicans) you mention appears to have had much more to do with domestic policies.